# Gradle : How to define a task that depend on an ant target

Tags: ant, gradle, taskdef

Hi if i list all tasks with `gradle testGradle` tasks -- all I see all imported ant tasks, but when i try to create my task that depends on an ant task, I am getting "Could not determine the dependencies of task ':testGradle'.

the line that is a problem: `task testGradle(dependsOn: 'init' )` - it clearly doesn't see ant init task.

What did I do wrong?

### build.gradle

```
println "this will always runs  first"
task buildM << {
  println "Importing ..."
  ant.importBuild  'build.xml'
  println "Done importing"
}

task testGradle(dependsOn : init ) << {
  println tasks.getByPath('init').path
}
```

### gradle tasks all

### Other tasks

all
    compile - Compile main source tree java files

```
deploy - deploy WAR file
**init** - Prepare for running compiling artifacts
....
```

byWorld5
copyTestConfiguration - Copy unit test configurations
deployLoggerProperties - Deploy logging.properties to tomcat
execMoped
importTasks
install - Install application in Tomcat
list - List Tomcat applications
init - Prepare for running compiling artifacts
reload - Reload application in Tomcat
start - Start Tomcat application
stop - Stop Tomcat application
test - Run junit tests
    compile - Compile main source tree java files

```
init - Prepare for running compiling artifacts
```

### **> gradle -v**

### Gradle 1.1

Gradle build time: Tuesday, July 31, 2012 1:24:32 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_24 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b12)
OS: Linux 2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.x86_64 amd64

**>gradle -c**

org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'moped_gradle'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:463)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:75)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:439)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:434)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:173)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:138)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'init' on root project 'moped_gradle'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:60)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.propertyMissing(BasicScript.java:70)
    at build_62g86rvs7k0vqsu3ssgdsrobsc.run(/home/natalik/MyInstalls/moped_gradle/build.gradle:14)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 33 more

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post, show *all* relevant parts of the build script, the *full* error message, the full stack trace (`-s`), and output of `gradle -v`?

Comment: I added gradle -c and gradle -v to my post Here is my build.gradle

Comment: Problems happens in testGradle(dependsOn : init ),if I'll make it dependsOn: buildM, everything runs just fine.

Comment: Your **ant.importBuild** needs to either go outside of all tasks, or inside of all the relevant tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The `ant.importBuild` statement must be called during configuration phase to work.
I did it during execution.